# Windows Remote Registry/DCOM access without SMBv1

Tags: windows, smb, jenkins, dcom

Admin has disabled SMBv1 on our VMs because of some vulnerability. However, that broke our Jenkins slave nodes because the master cannot connect to the slave. Is there a solution for remote registry/DCOM without SMBv1 enabled?

Comment: What part of Jenkins is accessing registry and DCOM, is that a plugin?

Comment: @eckes: Not. That is required by (at least the old) Jenkins to start the Jenkins slave.

Comment: Hm, then Jenkins needs to move to a smbj/smbj-rpc based solution which supports SMB 2.0.

Comment: I cannot think of any other solution except to configure the Jenkins to use SMBv2.  Your Administrator should be able to do that.  Of course a better solution to breaking things, is to install the patch, that patches the SMBv1 vulnerability and then on your own timeline update  Jenkins configuration to use SMBv2+